# Error - installing Adobe Flash Player: "The installer you are trying to use is corrupted or incomplete."

Tags: flash

I am using Windows 7 64 bits and Chrome browser.

When I try to install Adobe Flash player I get this error:

"NSIS Error
The installer you are trying to use is corrupted or incomplete.
This could be the result of a damaged disk, a failed download or a virus.

You may want to contact the author of this installer to obtain a new copy.

It may be possible to skip this check using the /NCRC command line switch
(NOT RECOMMENDED)."

Any idea what is the problem?

Answer (score 2):

I've had that issue with other programs on machines with rootkits.

Invalid installers are often (but not always) corrupted because they a)didn't finish downloading, or b) have been modified by a rootkit or virus.

I don't want to sound like I'm parroting the error message that you got. 
I've seen this on a Windows XP machine while installing various antivirus programs to clean up a rootkit.

The virus kept "eating" at the installers. I downloaded to a disc on a another machine and it ran some of the installers that way. 
(Incidentally, the end result was a reinstall anyways - the virus was just too much for the machine.)

Comment: I have occasionally had the same issue with Firefox and Norton combination. Sometimes Norton's scan prevents the file from downloading completely though Firefox renames is from a .part to the expected type.

Answer (score 0):

Adobe does not officially [support that combination](http://www.adobe.com/products/flashplayer/systemreqs/) of browser and OS. Although you should verify you are downloading the [appropriate installer](http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/thankyou/xpi/?installer=Flash_Player_10_for_Windows_-_Other_Browsers&d=McAfee_Security_Scan) then check out the supported browsers. Listed for Windows 7 is:

```
Microsoft Internet Explorer 8.0 or later, Firefox 3.x or later
```

although you could try installing it in Vista compatibility mode, it's worth a shot.

Comment: Flash and windows 7 64 bit and chrome is working at home but not at work.

Answer (score 0):

I have Flash working in Google Chrome in Windows 7 (32 bit).

You could try [uninstalling flash](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/141/tn_14157.html) then reinstalling.